# How can I account for headers that don't follow proper capitalization?

Tags: php, header, case-sensitive, array-key

**Updated Question:**

When using `get_headers()` with the `format` option to use named array keys (rather than numbered keys), how can I account for situations like the server using `Content-type` rather than `Content-Type`?

---

**Original Question:** PHP problem getting header of a file that has a colon in url
<strike>Hi, I am having trouble retrieving header information of a remote url which has a colon in it. I have tried using urldecode and it decodes %3A into :, however it does not solve the problem. What to do?

This url: 
http://string-theory.wdfiles.com/local--files/char%3Ajezebel/evangeline-lilly-picture-4a.jpg</strike>

Comment: Please show some code and an example URL

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer:**

If you can't guarantee that the server uses correct capitalization, you can use `array_change_key_case` to change the named keys.

```
<?php
    $original = array('Content-type'=>'text/html');
    echo $original['Content-Type']; // Notice: Undefined index

    $fixed = array_change_key_case($original, CASE_LOWER);
    echo $fixed['content-type']; // prints 'text/html'
?>
```

---

**Old Answer:**

You're going to have to expand on your question, because this works just perfectly:

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://www.mysite.com/dev/blah.php?blah=1:2:3';
    print_r(get_headers($url));
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Date: Tue, 22 Feb 2011 18:28:20 GMT
    [2] => Server: Apache
    [3] => Connection: close
    [4] => Content-Type: text/html
)
```

**Output 2:** (using URL given by OP)

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.0 200 OK
    [1] => Etag: "8b48b69ed24101b9a235e0168874c720"
    [2] => Content-type: image/jpeg; charset=utf-8
    [3] => Content-Length: 482111
    [4] => Connection: close
    [5] => Date: Wed, 23 Feb 2011 19:50:42 GMT
    [6] => Server: lighttpd/wikidot
)
```

Comment: Try to get this one: 

http://string-theory.wdfiles.com/local--files/char%3Ajezebel/evangeline-lilly-picture-4a.jpg

Comment: @John: Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.0 200 OK
    [1] => Etag: "8b48b69ed24101b9a235e0168874c720"
    [2] => Content-type: image/jpeg; charset=utf-8
    [3] => Content-Length: 482111
    [4] => Connection: close
    [5] => Date: Wed, 23 Feb 2011 18:30:54 GMT
    [6] => Server: lighttpd/wikidot
)

Comment: I've tested using both `%3A` and `:` in the `$url` variable.. both work fine. You should edit your Question with the code you're using, because it's most likely some other issue.

Comment: I found the problem: When using the optional parameter for the get_headers function to assign array keys as the name of the header tag, for some reason in this url, php assign "Content-Type" as "Content-type" (lower case t in type). This was giving me problems in my script...

Comment: How so? Were you trying something like `$array['Content-Type']` or `if ($key == 'Content-Type')` ?

Comment: Using "$array['Content-Type']". I used the function array_change_key_case to lower all cases and then use content-type, works now!

Comment: @John: I've submitted an edit for your question, so it better reflects your actual issue. My answer has been updated with relevant information.